# How to assign the value passed to a bootstrap modal dialogue to php variable?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am passing value to a bootstarp modal form like this -

`echo '<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541" data-toggle="modal" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog" href="#addBookDialog">';`

**javascript:**

```
<script>
 $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
 var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
 $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
 $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

And receiving it in a text area like this -

`echo '<textarea name="bookId" id="bookId"></textarea>';`

Now my question is how to get this value into a php variable say `$receivedValue`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to POST it to your PHP script using AJAX-request or plain form submission.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can think about is to use post or get method threw the '$.ajax' method.
Here is the code that you need:

```
.ajax({
    url : "URL of the php script", 
    type: "POST",
    data : //The data that you want to pass
    success: function(res)
    {
         //code if everything passed fine
     }
     });
```